# Clojurescript - update-in a Javascript map

Tags: clojurescript

How do I apply a given function to a JavaScript JSON structure ?

I would like to be able to do the following :

```
(update-in js-data [.-data] my-fn)  ;; fails since .-data is not valid
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`update-in` and similar functions only work on ClojureScript data structures.

In your specific example you could convert js-data to a ClojureScript data structure like this

```
(update-in (js->clj js-data) ["data"] my-fn)
```

If you cannot convert the Javascript object to a plain map you can always modify the original object in-place using `set!`.

```
(set! js-data -data my-fn)
```

Comment: Well in that specific case I couldn't convert it (I'll have to try again, but that seems overkill). A version using Javascript interop would be very welcome.

Comment: Implementing the IAssoc protocol with extend-type for Object can probably make update-in work with js objects. Not sure though.